# Closing a socket server side on socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm pretty sure this is a simple question, but I have no idea where the socket.io docs are and  the one at http://labs.learnboost.com/socket.io/ don't really help.

So let's say I have a socket.io http server and written a website to connect to it.

1. How do I provide protection to the server so that unauthorized people(people who connected not through the website) will be blocked/dropped/banned.
2. How do I end a socket connection on the server side? So If I have

   ```
   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('end', function() {
       var i = global_sockets_list.indexOf(socket);
       global_sockets_list.splice(i, 1);
     });

     socket.emit('end'); // Doesn't work, just sends data
     socket.end(); //error

   });
   ```

How do I end a socket connection? (The connect then disconnect above is for testing)

Comment: how are people connecting in an unauthorized fashion. I am working with socket.io and was curious to make sure the web server with socket.io is secured.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try calling:

```
socket.disconnect('unauthorized');
```

or

```
socket.close();
```

EDIT: You might be able to check the referer header. Look at [Socket.io Security Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450445/socket-io-security-issues) for more info.

Comment: socket.close() doesn't work, but socket.disconnect() did. THX, btw do u know where the full documentation for socket.io is?

Comment: There really isn't any good detailed documentation beyond the wiki (see https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki). In my case I open up the socket.io source code and look for suitably named functions (like `disconnect` or `close` :)).

Comment: Do you know the answer to my question part 1?

Comment: There is additional documentation here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/client.js#L108-L122

Answer (score 13):

On the server side there is a [socket.disconnect](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/876833198dcae62521f0706e3f381c094db2faf5/lib/socket.js#L438) method that takes a boolean meaning close the underlying transport connection. Here's the source code with docs as of July 2010:

```
/**
 * Disconnects this client.
 *
 * @param {Boolean} if `true`, closes the underlying connection
 * @return {Socket} self
 * @api public
 */

Socket.prototype.disconnect = function(close){
  if (!this.connected) return this;
  if (close) {
    this.client.disconnect();
  } else {
    this.packet({ type: parser.DISCONNECT });
    this.onclose('server namespace disconnect');
  }
  return this;
};
```

So you should call `socket.disconnect(true);`

Comment: Upvote for this one because while `'unauthorized'` works, it works because it's _truthy_; this is the more appropriate way of using the `disconnect` function.