# How to remove io.on('connection') listener?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have some code for a socket.io server along the lines of:

```
var io = require("socket.io");
io = io(server);
io.on('connection', connectionHandler);
```

This all works great.  I'm wondering how I can remove that connection listener - unlike socket, it appears that

```
io.removeListener('connection', connectionHandler);
```

doesn't work (I get "io.removeListener is not a function").  How do I remove that on('connection') listener?

If it matters, I'm working on a socket.io room managing library, and am writing a reset function.  I'm using the reset function between test suites with Mocha.  I'd like the reset function to remove the on connection listener.

Socket.io version is 1.3.7

Comment: Possibly a duplicate to [this Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092624/socket-io-removing-specific-listener)

Comment: That's referring to the socket - I'm wondering about how to do the same for the server.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to closing the connection ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7492995/2619658

Comment: Just a guess - `io.off`?

Comment: io.off() doesn't exist, but io.close() does, so that shuts down the server.  But then, how do I reopen the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you work through how socket.io processes `.on()`, one can figure out that it's using the default top-level namespace as the `EventEmitter` and `io.on()` just forwards the function call to the top-level namespace object.  So, you can get the top level namespace object and then just call any `EventEmitter` method on it like this:

```
var nsp = io.of('/');
nsp.removeListener('connection', connectionHandler);
```

I have verified that this works in my own test app and stepped through it in the debugger to verify it was working as expected.