# Difference between disconnect, close & destroy methods of socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a simple chat application using [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) & [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io).

I'm trying to terminate the connection, for example when the user choose to leave a namespace, or something similar to logout, which doesn't exit the application or trigger a reload.

I've checked this issue @ [GitHub](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/47), as well as these questions,

- [Node.js: socket.io close client connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126677/node-js-socket-io-close-client-connection)
- [Closing a socket server side on socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492966/closing-a-socket-server-side-on-socket-io)
- [How to close a socket.io connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953658/how-to-close-a-socket-io-connection)

They suggest different methods such as `disconnect`, `close` etc.

As per my own experiments based on these,

Both `disconnect`, `close` methods sets the socket's `connected` property to false and `disconnected` property to true as you can see below.

> [image]

I've also noticed a `destroy` method in the socket's prototype:

> [image]

Can someone describe what exactly these methods are for, and how they are different from each other..?

---

Side note: It'd be great if someone can share any reference to documentation for these methods

Comment: Hahaha, sensible documentation for socket.io? Not gonna happen.

Comment: haha that didn't age well.

Answer (score 11):

These are the [typescript definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/socket.io-client/index.d.ts) in VSCODE:

```
    /**
     * Disconnects the socket manually
     * @return This Socket
     */
    close():Socket;

    /**
     * @see close()
     */
    disconnect():Socket;
```

Not too helpful. Looking at the Socket.IO source code for [`close`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/client.js#L140-L152):

```
/**
 * Closes the underlying connection.
 *
 * @api private
 */
Client.prototype.close = function(){
  if ('open' == this.conn.readyState) {
    debug('forcing transport close');
    this.conn.close();
    this.onclose('forced server close');
  }
};
```

And for [`disconnect`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/client.js#L108-L122):

```
/**
 * Disconnects from all namespaces and closes transport.
 *
 * @api private
 */
Client.prototype.disconnect = function(){
  for (var id in this.sockets) {
    if (this.sockets.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      this.sockets[id].disconnect();
    }
  }
  this.sockets = {};
  this.close();
};
```

It looks like `disconnect` calls `close` after doing additional disconnecting work. I would recommend calling `disconnect` when you want to close, instead of just calling `close`.