# Enhancing Security in a now.js/socket.io chat

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

A chat with [nowjs](http://nowjs.org) or [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is one of the easiest exercises you can perform with them. I want to implement a multi-room chat (with a non-fixed number of rooms and logged users), using nowjs' Group objects.

I've not worked with WebSockets directly, yet, and I want to know what security concerns are there. For example, how often do I have to check for authentication?

Is it possible for an attacker to "hijack" a socket.io connection and how can I prevent it?

What other security traps are there to be concerned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Man-in-the-middle is certainly a consideration. The biggest security issue, though, would be XSS.

[This useful SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450445/socket-io-security-issues) suggests:

1. socket.io 0.8 has referrer verification built in
2. if chat is from known origin, block superfluous connections at the firewall

[This very informative article](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/03/html5-websockets-security-new-tool-for.html) suggests:

1. don't trust the client
2. use SSL encryption
3. check the origin
4. prevent XSS (sanitize client input!)
5. don't assume it's a browser

[This useful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl) says to set secure:true on socket.io.connect(...)

I'd recommend taking all those suggestions :)